# f# get index of all NaNs in a float array

Tags: f#

I am relatively new to f# and still learning. I am trying to write a function that returns the indices of all NAN of a float array as int array option.

```
let arr = [1.0; 2.0; nan: 2.0; 4.5; nan; nan; 3.0;]
```

I have a fct that returns the index of the first nan by using Array.tryFindIndex.
But now i am stuck and don't know what to do to get the other nan out of the array and in the.
This is what my code looks like:

```
let indexOfOneNan (arr:array<float>) =
    arr
    |> Array.tryFindIndex (fun f -> nan.Equals(f))
    |> fun b -> match b with
            | Some (x) -> Some ([|x|])
            | None     -> None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly possible to apply the predicate repeatedly, in order to retrieve all elements that satisfy it and not only the first, but it would involve the allocation of a new array for each step. This wouldn't be very efficient.

You could use the `Array.mapi` projection instead, which passes the index along with each element to your predicate, and remove all elements which do not satisfy the predicate by `Array.choose`.

```
let arr = [|1.0; 2.0; nan; 2.0; 4.5; nan; nan; 3.0;|]

arr
|> Array.mapi (fun i f ->
    if System.Double.IsNaN f then Some i else None )
|> Array.choose id
// val it : int [] = [|2; 5; 6|]
```

*EDIT:*

Alternatively you could utilize an `array sequence expression` as per the [f# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/) , or `array comprehension`, colloquially. They are often more concise for this kind of problem.

```
[| for i, f in Array.mapi (fun i f -> i, f) arr do
    if System.Double.IsNaN f then yield i |]
// val it : int [] = [|2; 5; 6|]
```